# SAP business objects agg totals

Tags: business-objects

I have difficulty aggregating without showing each car ID (column) from the data set below.

I’d like to show total results where the date is greater than the date with flag=Y by car.

Results:

```
CT(times) count(unique car count)
2         1
1         1
```

Sample Data Set:

```
Car     DT       Flag  Key   CT
123     1/1/15   N     234   1
123     6/7/19   N     236   1
123     1/1/14   Y     787   1
234     7/5/12   Y     765   1
234     8/1/19   N     789   1
234     7/2/11   N     156   1
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: What specific tool within BusinessObjects are you using? Web Intelligence?

Comment: Yes, web intelligence!